# Why I am getting prompt when manipulating df created from another df

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have the below codes:

```
#converts SQLite data to a Panda data frame
df1 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Accounts", conn)
df2 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Rates", conn)
df3 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Clients", conn)

#Create new data frame as working space
dfnew= df1[['Client','Product','CCY','Balance']]

#map Currency code
dfnew['fxrate'] = dfnew.CCY.map(df2.set_index('Currency code')['Rate'])

dfnew.head()
```

When I run the results, the output is as expected. However I'm getting a message below:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:14: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

What does this mean?
Something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

dfnew is not a new dataframe but a view of df1

You should make a copy:

```
#Create new data frame as working space
dfnew = df1[['Client','Product','CCY','Balance']].copy()
```

*NB. You should read the link in the warning message, this explains the problematic in great length*